# Heat equation with nonhomogeneous convection on half-line with conservation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $v(t)$ be a differentiable function, and consider a solution to the
nonhomogeneous heat conduction problem: A solution $u$ such that
\begin{align}
&u_t = \frac{1}{2}u_{xx} + v(t)u_x, x > 0\\
&u_x(t, 0) = -2v(t)y(t, 0).
\end{align}
Say we have an initial condition of $u_0 = f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0.$

My question is two fold: I would like to use energy estimates but need 
a priori bounds of the form 
$$\lim_{M\to\infty}u_x(t, M) \to 0?$$

Can we find some explicit solution which will give regularity of $u,$ and
what assumptions would be necessary to place on $f$ and $v?$